# How to auto-populate parent field with a lookup field value from child

Tags: triggers, salesforce, lookup, soql, sfdc

There is a text field Editor__c in Account object and lookup field User__c in Contact object. As soon as I select a value from User__c lookup field and save it the same value should be automatically updated in the Editor__c field if the profile is of Editor

I tried with flows and trigger but couldn’t find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Collect the ids in 1 loop. Check if they're right profile. Loop again and update accounts.
You'll have to think what should happen if somebody updates 2 contacts at same time, which value should win.

```apex
trigger HiStack on Contact(after update){
Set<Id> candidates = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact c : trigger.new){
    Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
    if(c.User__c != old.User__c && c.User__c != null){
        candidates.add(c.User__c);
    }
}
if(!candidates.isEmpty()){
    Map<Id, User> editors = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :candidates AND Profile.Name = 'Editor']);
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();
    if(!editors.isEmpty()){
        for(Contact c : trigger.new){
            if(c.User__c != old.User__c && editors.containsKey(c.Id)){
                accountsToUpdate.put(c.AccountId, new Account(Id = c.AccountId, Editor__c = c.User__c));
        }
        update accountsToUpdate.values();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This solution isn’t working…it gives error that variable does not exist: old in the second for loop

Comment: We can directly use trigger.oldMap.get(c.ID). User__c instead of assigning to another object

Comment: old will be wrong value (when you swap editor from user1 to user2) or even null (when you set editor for 1st time). And ideally you do want to have query not in a loop... You do need the profile check, right? I mean... post your own answer what you finally ended up with and people may point out ifn there are flaws that'll bite you in future...

Comment: Yeah sure will post…but your solution isn’t working either because the object old isnt declared in the second for loop…the contact’s parent should be equal to the account name..that condition also needs to be added i guess..please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Fair, I didn't redeclare `old`, easy to add, 1-liner. Not sure what do you mean by "contact's parent" though? There's no standard field like that on Contact, something custom you have? How are internet strangers supposed to know that? Post what you have.